# installing conda gives 'os no space left' error on virtual box ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, virtualbox

I tried installing conda distro in my ubuntu that sits inside virtual box.
I allocated 10g for ram.

It gives me "Os error: no space left on device"

I tried sudo apt autoremove, no luck.

I'm actually trying to also install Nvidia proprietary drivers and use them from this virtual ubuntu.

Comment: VM Guests cannot interact with hardware by default. Hardware is the Host OS and Host kernel's domain. Some hardware (like USB) can be passed through the host. Check your VM Host application settings to see if what you want is possible.

Comment: I read the question as you didn't provide enough disk space; the recommend for Ubuntu desktop (inc. 18.04) is 25GB, but you didn't specify if you are talking about server or desktop (the nvidia drivers to me imply desktop), nor what space you allocated.

Comment: @guiverc , wow, i did not know about 25gb recomendation.. yes, it's ubuntu desktop - just ubuntu on virtual box

Comment: @user535733, that's what i m asking about - how to emulate or access that actual physical videocard i have on my laptop?

Comment: FYI:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  but the requirements depend on your end-use-case. I find 25GB low, most find it far more than needed (you need space to add software, plus *release-upgrade* when that time comes.. if you plan on *nuke & re-install* the space required to *release-upgrade* (download new packages, install new packages before old-packages can be cleaned at the end, ie. GBs of free disk space required for *release-upgrade* to occur) mean you can adjust by needs, but with no space left - consider the minimum recommended & maintain your system)